# mysql: ROLLUP on TOP, SUM(FINANCIAL AMOUNT), then order FINANCIAL AMOUNT column by DATETIME DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by, rollup

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE tblFinancials
(
pkFinancialID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fkUserID int(11),
fkProfileID int(11),
fkFinancialEntryID int(11),
FinancialAmount decimal(10,2),
FinancialDateTime datetime
);

pkFinancialID  fkUserID  fkProfileID  fkFinancialEntryID  FinancialAmount  FinancialDateTime
1              1         1            1                   100.00           2014-06-07 07:00:00
2              1         1            2                   100.00           2014-06-08 08:00:00
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE tblFinancialEntry
(
pkFinancialEntryID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FinancialEntry varchar(255)
);

pkFinancialEntryID  FinancialEntry
1                   Credit
2                   Debit
```

**Table 3**

```
CREATE TABLE tblUsers
(
pkUserID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
UserName varchar(255)
);

pkUserID  UserName
1         Test User
```

**Table 4**

```
CREATE TABLE tblProfiles
(
pkProfileID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fkUserID int(11),
ProfileName varchar(255)
);

pkProfileID  fkUserID
1            1
```

**Desired query result:**

```
Total Due:      0.00
             -100.00   2014-06-07 07:00:00
              100.00   2014-06-08 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the debit/credit thing for you to incorporate:

```
select concat(
   case when T.pkFinancialID is null 
        then 'Total Due:     '
        else '               '
   end,  cast(FinancialTotalAmount as char(20))
   ) 

 , case when T.pkFinancialID is null
        then null
        else FDateTime
   end
from (
    select pkFinancialID
     , max(FinancialDateTime) as FDateTime
     , SUM(CASE WHEN fkFinancialEntryID = 1 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE -1 
       END * FinancialAmount) as FinancialTotalAmount
    from tblFinancials 
    WHERE tblFinancials.fkUserID = 1 
      AND tblFinancials.fkProfileID = 1 
    group by pkFinancialID with rollup
) as T  
order by case when T.pkFinancialID is null then 0 else 1 end
       , FDateTime;


Total Due: 0.00     (null)
         100.00     June, 07 2014 07:00:00+0000
        -100.00     June, 08 2014 08:00:00+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN pkID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, EntryTotalAmount
```

`pkID` will be null for the rollupped row. By mapping null to 0 and not null to 1 we make sure that the rollupped rows are sorted first and after that `EntryTotalAmount` is used for internal sorting within those partitions.

#### Updated Queury

`SELECT ifnull(pkFinancialID,'Total Due:') as pkFinancialID
      , CASE WHEN fkFinancialEntryID = 1 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE -1 
        END * SUM(FinancialAmount) as FinancialTotalAmount
      , FinancialAmount, FinancialDescription, FinancialDateTime, fkUserID 
FROM (
    select pkFinancialID, fkFinancialCodeTypeID, fkFinancialEntryID
         , CASE WHEN fkFinancialEntryID = 1 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE -1 
           END * SUM(FinancialAmount) as FinancialTotalAmount
         , FinancialAmount, FinancialDescription, FinancialDateTime, fkUserID
         , fkProfileID 
    from tblFinancials 
    WHERE tblFinancials.fkUserID = 1 
      AND tblFinancials.fkProfileID = 1 
    group by pkFinancialID with rollup
) r 
WHERE r.fkUserID = 1 
  AND r.fkProfileID = 1 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN pkFinancialID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, FinancialTotalAmount;`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for; it returns the results needed. I was almost there, thanks!

Comment: @Lennart How would I convert EntryTotalAmount to a negative number if I add a new field called fkCodeID = 1. (CASE WHEN fkCodeID = 1 THEN (SUM(EntryTotalAmount)) ELSE (-SUM(EntryTotalAmount)) END)

Comment: Try: `CASE WHEN fkCodeID = 1 THEN -1 else 1 END * SUM(EntryTotalAmount)`

Comment: Bummer, I see it's the other way around: `CASE WHEN fkCodeID = 1 THEN 1 else -1 END * SUM(EntryTotalAmount)`. Assuming fkCodeID is either 0 or 1 `coalesce(nullif(fkCodeID,0),-1) * SUM(EntryTotalAmount)` is an alternative

Comment: @Lennart I incorporated some additions from Alex Jordan. You might want to... check it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working as I'd like. I updated original post so that you can see the current query. rollup should have SUM of FinancialTotalAmount. Expecting to SUM negative and positive numbers based on fkFinancialEntryID. fkCodeID has been renamed to fkFinancialEntryID. pkID has been renamed to pkFinancialID. EntryTotalAmount has been renamed to FinancialAmount.

Comment: create an sqlfiddle that illustrates the problem, (or provide create table- and insert -statements)

Comment: "FinancialAmount" is positive numbers. If fkFinancialEntryID = 2 then I'd like "FinancialAmount" only for that record to be a negative number and then sum. "fkFinancialEntryID" is Credits and Debits. 1 = Credit (Positive Number), 2 = Debit (Negative Number)

Comment: @Lennart: I provided the table structure for you.